# Flutter- adjust the custom button tap area

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```dart
    Widget customButton() {
    return Container(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.amber,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          child: Icon(Icons.auto_fix_normal),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I'm trying to create custom button with inkwell, but button can tapping from the outside of the button . How i can adjust the button tap area ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `customBorder: CircleBorder()`, on InkWell fixed the splash effect, but to work it properly I am extending the snippet.

```dart
 Widget customButton() {
      return Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.orange,
          shape: const CircleBorder(),
          child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.black,
            onTap: () {},
            customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
            child: Ink(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: const Icon(Icons.holiday_village),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's slightly more optimal and easier to understand solution than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72273058/1714102).

```dart
class CircleIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  const CircleIcon({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Ink(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.orange,
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.black,
        onTap: () {},
        customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
        child: const Icon(Icons.holiday_village),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`InkWell` ripple effect is drawn on the closest `Material` widget up in a widget tree. [Ink](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Ink/Ink.html) gives possibility to draw InkWell on the `Ink` itself without necessity to use `Material`. `Ink` is more specialized (supports width, height, padding, decoration - more control over the appearance and behavior of the effect) than rather big `Material` widget.

As a result, the widget tree is tiny.

I also don't return widget in a function, because [it's discouraged](https://dartcodemetrics.dev/docs/rules/flutter/avoid-returning-widgets).