# I don't see tap effect while tapping on icon button in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created a product tile and there is a IconButton,

When I tap on icon button it does not show tapping effect (like a circle is shown while tapping)

And I notice that tap effect is showing behind the grid's tile...

so what is my mistake... I have attached an image to explain what I mean to..
[image]

and here is my productive widget code

```
class ProductTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final double price;
  final bool isfav;
  final String imageurl;
  final MaterialColor color;

  const ProductTile(
      {Key? key,
      required this.name,
      required this.isfav,
      required this.color,
      required this.imageurl,
      required this.price})
      : super(key: key);

  final double borderradius = 20;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white,width: 2),
          boxShadow: const [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(104, 104, 104, 0.2),
                offset: Offset(3, 4),
                spreadRadius: 1,
                blurRadius: 3)
          ],
          color: color[50],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderradius),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            //price
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: color,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(borderradius),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(borderradius))),
                  child: Text(
                    '\$' + price.toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              //todo cant understand
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 36, vertical: 12),
              child: Image.asset(imageurl),
            ),
            Text(
              name.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: color, fontSize: 20),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 4,
            ),
            Text(
              'Logic',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print('cant see click animation');
                      },
                      icon: isfav == true
                          ? Icon(Icons.favorite)
                          : Icon(Icons.favorite_outline)),
                  TextButton(
                      //color: Colors.grey,
                      onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Buy',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),))
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove  `Container`'s color and  use `Material`'s color like

```dart
  child: Material(
        color: color[50],
        child: Container(
```

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72273058/10157127)

Comment: It is solved but can't understand why its happening...its showing TextButton's tap effect and not showing IconButton's tap effect.....not getting whats the exact reason..y to user material

Comment: Based on my understanding, the splash color gets overlap by container's  color.

Comment: yes..got it..I checked with another example and its the same..IconButton's colour is not appearing due to container colour

Comment: There might be something with  [MaterialType](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialType.html)